# Netsuite Manufacturing - Assemblies to inherit attributes from member items

Tags: netsuite

Can Assemblies inherit or display the attributes of member items? The source of truth for the Assembly is not the fields on the Assembly record, but rather lives at the member item level below, so I want to avoid duplicating data.

We're manufacturing assemblies of electronics, the BOM has many entries of member items and one of the member items is an LED array. LED array comes in 5 different types, each with a different wattage W, 8W or 12W etc.

If the member items have an attribute for 8W or 12W etc, can the Assembly/BOM record inherit or otherwise display the attribute from the member item?

Again I want to avoid duplicating data that already exists elsewhere.

Comment: From what you're saying, it sounds like you want to include an attribute already assigned to your item (I'm guessing inventory) that is the wattage, and then show it at the bom-level on the assemblies that inventory can be found on ? Or do you want to select the wattage to apply at the bom-item level

Comment: @SimonDelicata I want to select wattage from the component level (aka member item) and apply to the assembly (aka BOM / parent) record.